# Prevent Vertically Merged Cells from Breaking Across Pages

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I would like to prevent vertically merged cells in tables that I generate from a word document template from breaking across pages programmatically using Office Open XML. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24565788/1698964) that I could add the properties "KeepNext" and "Keep Lines" to the paragraphs within the table cells that are vertically merged. However, if I apply the setting to the all of the rows in the table, the rows keep splitting when a new page is inserted in the formatting. All of the rows have the property "Allow row to break across pages" deselected. Here is the xml of one of the rows that gets splitted across pages.

```
<w:tr>
    <w:trPr>
      <w:cantSplit />
      <w:trHeight w:val="20" />
    </w:trPr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="283" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>51</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="676" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>TARJETA DE CRÉDITO</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>REVOLVENTE</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>INDIVIDUAL</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>BANCO</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="283" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>MX</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>08/12/2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>20/10/2009</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>14/11/2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="709" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>02/05/2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>14/11/2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="425" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t />
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>8000</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>10706</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>0</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="576" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>6799</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="558" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t />
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="567" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>0</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>PAGO MINIMO</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="671" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>97=CUENTA CON DEUDA PARCIAL O TOTAL SIN RECUPERAR</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="547" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vMerge w:val="restart" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>05</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>31/10/2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>3296</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="547" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>2012</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="547" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>2011</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="523" w:type="dxa" />
        <w:vAlign w:val="center" />
      </w:tcPr>
      <w:p>
        <w:pPr>
          <w:jc w:val="center" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial" />
            <w:sz w:val="6" />
            <w:szCs w:val="6" />
            <w:lang w:val="es-ES" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>2010</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
```

This is the result that I get so far:

[image]

However, this is what I would like to get (eventually).

[image]

Let me know if I can add more helpful information, as I am running out of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT apply KeepNext to the LAST paragraph in a table cell. That will allow Word to break the page at the end of a row.

The most efficient way would be a pair of styles for the paragraphs in the table, one with KeepNext the other without. All the formatting that repeats itself for every cell (w:pPr and w:rPr) in the sample you show us would then be unnecessary: less code for you to write and smaller file size!

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but I suspect this is a case where Microsoft Word does not support the standard, but where the Microsoft has documented the lack of support. In [MS-OI29500].pdf ("Office Implementation Information for ISO/IEC 29500 Standards Support") I see:

> 2.1.118 Part 1 Section 17.4.6, cantSplit (Table Row Cannot Break Across Pages)
>       a. The standard states that the row shall start on a new page and flow onto multiple pages as necessary when the contents of the table row cannot fit on a single page.
>       Word starts the row on a new page and cuts off overflowing contents as necessary under this circumstance.

Which I *think* is what you are actually seeing. If so, my guess is that no single approach to "keeping" or "splitting" will work in every situation, and that you may have to hard-code a choice based on some other criterion (e.g., I'd rather split at *this point* than let Word get it wrong).

Comment: I can see your point. I was thinking about finding out a sort of "page break" tag within the xml for the row. Once I had found out the "page break" tag within the row I would apply some formatting to it to either keep it in the page or somehow move it to the next page. However, I remember reading that those tags are added after the document is opened with a word processor.