# WordProcessing document

Tags: c#, openxml

I'm working in C# with the WordprocessingDocument class from openxml. My situation: I got some mht file which needs to be converted into docx. Problem lies with the tables. In some situation the data is not broken into new pages correctly, leaving an empty header in one page, and the table rows in the next page.

[image]

The magic fix in Word seems to be a check called "keep with next". If I apply that to the table header rows, all is well but that's not something our customer wants to do everytime.

I already figured out that I need to do something like below in my code:

```
new TableRow(
    new TableRowProperties(
        new CantSplit()),
```

But my problem is that I'm importing some external page into the document as an AltChunk (in the example the entire docx is build from code), so I got no clue on how to apply the CanSplit() class in my table. Any thoughts on how to get my tables from the AltChunk and apply the CanSplit()?!

I already spent quite some time figuring out a way to make this work properly, but to no avail sadly. Btw, I also tried adding page-break-inside: avoid styles to my table headers, but no surprise: it did not work as expected. Any thoughts on this matter?

Current code looks like this:

```
var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"]),
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        var template = GetUserTemplate(personId);
        var mhtmlMessage = GetMhtml(path, template, personId);
        var fileFullPath = WriteFile(path, template + ".mht", mhtmlMessage);
        var person = _personService.GetById(personId);
        var filename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomerName"] + "_" + person.FirstName + "_" + person.SurName + ".docx";

 using (var generatedDocument = new MemoryStream()){
            using (var myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)){
                var mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                if (mainPart == null){
                    mainPart = myDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                    new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
                }
                const string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
                var chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Mht, altChunkId);
                chunk.FeedData(System.IO.File.Open(fileFullPath, FileMode.Open));

                var altChunk = new AltChunk{Id = altChunkId};

                // ReSharper disable once PossiblyMistakenUseOfParamsMethod
                mainPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

                // I would like to access the tables inside the mht (altchunk) here and apply CantSplit() to each row.
                myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent tables from breaking over a page, if possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530954/prevent-tables-from-breaking-over-a-page-if-possible)

Comment: you should provide a bit more code to understand your difficulties

Comment: If you just need the tables do `myAltChunk.Descendants<Table>()`?

Comment: I think I already tried the Descendants<Table> and Descendants<TableRow> but this resulted in an empty array unfortunately...